# How to do an image gallery drag & sort in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an image gallery and I need to let the user to arrange them, something like https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

I tried to use jQueryUi sortable, but it show the error: TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

Any idea to do that in angular 2-6?

Comment: Do you need exactly the same as in your jquery example or you would need eventually additional things? If you need to have sophisticated grid ui most probably you need to use dragula and other libraries like gridster. If you need just what you refered to - its easy to do with no libraries. I can share how

Comment: I need exactly as in my jquery-ui example. I will write down the sollution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

At some user suggest (an answer that I can't find anymore), I've tried angular-sortablejs.
The result (for now) is a sortable image gallery like that:
[image]

npm -i angular-sortablejs --save

app.module.ts

`import {SortablejsModule} from 'angular-sortablejs'
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        SortablejsModule.forRoot({ animation: 150 })`

mycomponent.component.ts
`import {SortablejsModule} from 'angular-sortablejs';`

mycomponent.component.html

`<div class="row postgallery">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div id="multi" style="margin-left: 30px" [sortablejs]="images" [sortablejsOptions]="{ animation: 150 }">
             <div *ngFor="let item of images" class="imagecontainer">
                <div class="controls"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></a></div>
                <img src="{{item}}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

mycomponent.component.scss

```
.postgallery{
img{
    max-height: 200px; max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 13px 14px 0;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.imagecontainer{
    display: inline-block;

    .controls{
        display: block;position: absolute;
    }
}
```

}

The part that send the order to the server I didn't finish it yet.